# Random Value From ANY Enum

Tags: java, random, enums

I've got java enums all over the place, and while I've seen various good ways of selecting ones at random, it feels like there should be a way to do this generically; that is, one method for selecting a random value from any supplied enum. Say,

```
public static <E> E randomMember(Enum<E> enumeration){
...
}
```

Yet I can't figure out a way to do it, and the lack of Google results leads me to believe it isn't possible (or isn't a popular request, I guess).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing `enum`'s *class*, not `enum`'s *instance* to get this to work:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T randomMember(Class<T> enumType) {
    T[] constants = enumType.getEnumConstants();
    // Return a random element of constants array
}

...

MyEnum rand = randomMember(MyEnum.class);
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'll check this out now and report back but it looks like I yet again tripped over generics. Thanks a lot.